# Linking a visual sitemap with a web application

Tags: web-applications, sitemap

I have spent a LOT of time browsing the web to find a solution to my problem with no avail.

I have a web application with lots of pages. Many of the pages have their respective child pages, and some of these childs also have other childs, and so on. The web application is just the UI which means that it is the HTML mockups.

What I need is some way (obviously with the help of an application) how can I connect the folder which has all these HTML files with a visual Sitemap. I also need that when I create another HTML page in this folder, the sitemap will know and amend this page dyanamically. The same goes if a page is deleted etc...

I tried using the application [PowerMapper](http://www.powermapper.com/) but since my application has lots of javascript links which are connected to DIVs, SPANs and so on, instead of anchors, PowerMapper does not recognize these as links and therefore when the sitemap is created, there are lots of broken links, and PowerMapper does not allow you to change these. It just reads a website/web application and crawls is to create the visual sitemap.

Please, if anyone know about an application which lets you connect a sitemap to a folder which contains such HTML mockups and vice versa and you have total control over it, kindly let me know as I am totally lost.

Many thanks!

Comment: How would the sitemapper know about the javascript links? I mean, they're not physical links, and therefore they cannot be inspected. There are a lot of inherent problems around this: there are many ways to link things and dynamically change content in JavaScript, and many of these changes aren't actually new webpages, how would you map that? It's hard for a machine to understand the logic behind JavaScript links. This is why I hate JavaScript links ;)

Comment: Makes sense. The application I used (PowerMapper) can recognize javascript links but only if they are set somewhere in the page. If they are located in a div and called on clicked, it won't recognize them which is understandable. Basically, I need this system but I think it is impossible to achieve :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script using Selenium to spider the links. Maybe use http://selenium.rubyforge.org/ and a simple ruby script. Selenium is JS aware, just walk the DOM of each page and click each node.

You can also use watir, and firewatir , http://watir.com/

Comment: I don't usually use ruby but your solution seems what I am trying to do. Thanks I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a sitemap which shows connections for between pages if one links to another leads to an unreadable spiderweb... It's much better to show hierarchy of pages without regard for the links between them, e.g. as a pseudo-directory structure. Here's one which I have put together which is automatically generated from the site's navigational structure (which in this case is stored in a database, but in principle could be implicit in the directory structure of the pages): http://www.ewb.ca/en/sitemap.html

Is this the type of sitemap you're looking for? If not, can you post an image of the type of output you seek?